# Time-Series prediction in R caret package

Tags: r, time-series, r-caret, predict

I'm trying to predict future return using the `caret` package.

I know how to validate my model through [Time-series cross validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFKL8.png)
but I don't know how to get the latest prediction value.
As you can see in this picture,

[image]

last value is always used as "horizon"
I want to use this value as training data and get the last prediction even though I can't validate it anymore.
Should I use predict function? or Are there other good ways?

Here is my codes for building model and time-series validation.

```
timecontrol <- trainControl(method = 'timeslice', initialWindow = window_length, horizon =4, selectionFunction = "best", 
                        returnResamp = 'final', fixedWindow = TRUE, savePredictions = 'final') 


cur_val_m <- train(test_sample[,-1], test_sample[,1], method = "knn", 
                      trControl = timecontrol, tuneGrid = "knnGrid")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some part of your code or data. But, in general, if we need to predict one step ahead we can use this:

```
 prediction<-predict(model,yourdata[nrow(yourdata)+ 1,])
```

Comment: I executed your codes but It doesn't work. It says " variables in the training data missing in newdata ". I edited and add the my codes using caret package. Could you review this question again?..!

Comment: I mean I want to do h-step forecasting without adding independent variable.